# Cannot import python packages after update to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, updates, python, 22.04

I had Ubuntu 20.04 which I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04. I had installed many packages such as numpy, pandas, torch, etc on Ubuntu 20.04. However, after the update, it seems that none of the packages are to be found.

I get the following import error:

```
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Is there something that needs to be done to enable already installed third party packages after the update?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which python version are you using, probably there is incompatibility between python versions and plugins are thus not resolved or somewhat not found due to $PYTHONPATH change?

Comment: Currently I am using 3.10.4. I am sure that the original version of python was different. So, what should I do to fix this? Also, does a minor change in the python version cause such a big issue?

Comment: you may try to install python2

`sudo apt show python2` then `sudo apt install python2`
Package: python2
Version: 2.7.18-3
Section: universe/python
Source: python-defaults
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 70,7 kB
Provides: python-ctypes, python-email, python-importlib, python-profiler, python-wsgiref
Pre-Depends: python2-minimal (= 2.7.18-3)
Depends: python2.7 (>= 2.7.18~), libpython2-stdlib (= 2.7.18-3)...

Comment: Apparently the packages are under ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-package. But the variable $PYTHONPATH is empty. Changing that to point this directory should do the job right?

Comment: it's a path, so update your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (or /etc/environment or other shell config file locations to add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:pathxxx:pathxxy`) and reload config or terminal to take it into account